# How to bulk-update a SQL table with random data in one step?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a large table in which, for testing purposes, I want to update a column to a different random value on each row.

If I say:

```
update MyTable
set MyCol = Rand()*100
```

then the value is, indeed, random - but it's the same random number applied to every row.

I could use a cursor to iterate and update each row, one by one, and that's obviously what I'll fall back on if necessary.  But is there some SQL syntax that will update each row with a different random value, in one succinct statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to seed `RAND` with something new for each row:

`RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))`

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyCol = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10 as INT) + 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78a75/2

Answer (score 2):

You could seed the Random function with the primary key of the table?

```
update MyTable
set MyCol = Rand(MyIDColumn)*100
```

Comment: +1 It's a good answer - but seeding by ID column has the effect of making consecutive ID values generate "random" values that are very close to each other.  `NewID()` gets better results.